# Next.js - Material-ui css SSR not working with components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

After I build my project, I realized SSR for Material-ui not working on page where I used functional components.

My _document.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from '../lib/themes/hk-theme-light/index';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    const styledComponentsSheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const materialSheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
        ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: App => props => styledComponentsSheet.collectStyles(materialSheets.collect(<App {...props} />))
          })
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return {
          ...initialProps,
          styles: (
            <React.Fragment>
              {initialProps.styles}
              {materialSheets.getStyleElement()}
              {styledComponentsSheet.getStyleElement()}
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        }
      } finally {
        styledComponentsSheet.seal()
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="tr">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="theme-color"
            content={theme.palette.primary.main}
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Example Page:

```
import { DynamicTable } from '../../components/Table'
import { Section, DefaultContainer } from '../../components/elements/widgets'
import Layout from '../../layouts/LayoutDefault'


const IhtiyacKredisi = () => {
          <Layout>
            <Section>
                <DefaultContainer maxWidth={false}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item sm={12}>
                            <H2 variant="title">İhtiyaç Kredisi Maliyet Tablosu ve Örnek Hesaplama</H2>
                        </Grid>
                        <DynamicTable
                            tableData={ratesTable}
                            description={rateDescription}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </DefaultContainer>
            </Section>
        </Layout>

 }
```

With this code "jss-server-side" style is empty

[image: jss-server-side]

If I remove components and I add all functions and imports to page file It works well

[image]

I wonder what can cause this problem.

Comment: did you wrap your app with themeprovider

Answer (score 1):

The problem was key error. In component my key attribute was append by same name key={item.name}. So on build next.js doesn't compile critical css according to this error. I set key attribute by unique key. Problem fixed.

Comment: I can confirm this works; setting unique keys to each page components works. Why though? @BurakDuman